# Emacs 24 - How to create new function by repeat a command, persisting it to Emacs init file

Tags: function, emacs, repeat

To be more specific, I would like to create a function which repeat the built-in command 10 times: `enlarge-window`.

Comment: How about starting emacs maximised? (`-mm`)? :p

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `enlarge-window` tells us that the function takes an argument DELTA which is the number of lines to enlarge the window by, and that this value defaults to 1 line when called interactively:

```
enlarge-window is an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘window.el’.

It is bound to C-x ^.

(enlarge-window DELTA &optional HORIZONTAL)

Make the selected window DELTA lines taller.
Interactively, if no argument is given, make the selected window
one line taller.  If optional argument HORIZONTAL is non-nil,
make selected window wider by DELTA columns.  If DELTA is
negative, shrink selected window by -DELTA lines or columns.
```

As such, while you *could* write a function which calls `(enlarge-window 1)` ten times, you can more trivially call it once with a DELTA value of 10.

```el
(defun my-enlarge-window-10 ()
  "Make the selected window 10 lines taller."
  (interactive)
  (enlarge-window 10))
```

Note also that interactively you can use a *prefix argument* to pass a DELTA value to `enlarge-window`, and therefore you could also type one of the following to achieve the same result without a custom function:

- <kbd>C-u</kbd> `10` <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>
- <kbd>M-1</kbd><kbd>M-0</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>^</kbd>

Comment: Nice solution @phils.It works on my machine + emacs.